# Air Bubbles in Fuel Lines of Peugeot 206 HDI

Tags: fuel-system, peugeot

My car cut out while driving.  It wouldn't re-start and was showing signs of no fuel.  The car was taken to a garage and after 20 minutes, the mechanic said there was air in the lines. He very quickly decided it was the `high pressure pump` and it would be a very expensive repair. *He offered me scrap value!*

I got the car 2 days later and it started fine. It was ok for about 3 miles then it cut out again with same symptoms.

I pumped bulb until all air was out of lines. It would start and then cut straight out. I checked for air holes, but couldn't find anything.

**What are my options and what should I be looking for?**

Comment: What year is your car?  What bulb did you pump to get the air out of the lines?

Comment: Yes, please provide a years as I see most pumps pricing at about $100 so I find it hard that the car would not be worth fixing yourself.

Comment: Maybe pressure test the fuel lines? If you're getting air in the lines it could be a small leak at a fitting.

Comment: When was last time the fuel filter was replaced.  There are two rubber seals and one metallic.  If a recent replacement was done these are spots for air leaks.  If it has not been done for quite a while then they should be checked . --  Where is the air being detected at, the injectors or the filter area.